# Confusing utime and stime results

Tags: c, linux

I have the following program that opens and reads `smaps`, parse the contents to get some memory stats, prints the result on stdout, and then call `getrusage` and print the reported system and user time among other things:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void ko_(char const* ctx)
{ printf("Error %d (%s) %s.\n", errno, strerrorname_np(errno), ctx); }

struct mem_stats_
{
    int vm_kb; /* total virtual memory: anon + misc. */
        int anon_kb; /* anon = rss + swap + unallocated. */
            int rss_kb;
            int swap_kb;
            int unallocated_kb;
        int misc_kb; /* file-mappings + shared-memory */
};

// Call structure of the module
void print_perf_stats();
    static void print_cpu_stats_();
    static void print_mem_stats_();
        static int get_memstats_(struct mem_stats_* stats);
            static char* parse_VMA_(char* VMA, struct mem_stats_* stats);
                static char* jump_token_(char* str);
                static char* find_next_line_(char* str);
                static char* find_field_(char* str,
                                         char const* field, int field_sz,
                                         int* out);
                static char* find_next_VMA_(char* str);

void print_perf_stats()
{
    print_mem_stats_();
    print_cpu_stats_();
}

static void print_cpu_stats_()
{
    struct rusage usage;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);

    printf(
        "[Obs: CPUSTATS]"
        "[times u/s: %lds%ldus/%lds%ldus]"
        "[faults min/maj: %ld/%ld][cswitches (vol/unvol): %ld/%ld]\n",
        (long)usage.ru_utime.tv_sec, usage.ru_utime.tv_usec,
        (long)usage.ru_stime.tv_sec, usage.ru_stime.tv_usec,
        usage.ru_minflt, usage.ru_majflt, usage.ru_nvcsw, usage.ru_nivcsw
    );
}

static void print_mem_stats_()
{
    struct mem_stats_ stats;
    memset(&stats, 0, sizeof(stats));

    int ko = get_memstats_(&stats);

    if (ko)
        return;

    printf(
        "[Obs: MEMSTATS (kB)]"
        "[Vm: %d [PrvAnon: %d [Rss: %d][Swap: %d][Unalloc: %d]] [Misc: %d]]\n",
        stats.vm_kb,
        stats.anon_kb, stats.rss_kb, stats.swap_kb, stats.unallocated_kb,
        stats.misc_kb
    );
}

static int get_memstats_(struct mem_stats_* stats)
{
    size_t const buf_sz = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(buf_sz);

    FILE* f = fopen("/proc/self/smaps", "rb"); if (!f) goto e_open;
    int ko = setvbuf(f, NULL, _IONBF, 0);      if (ko) goto e_unbuf;
    size_t read = fread(buf, 1, buf_sz, f);    if (ferror(f)) goto e_read;
                                               if (read == buf_sz) goto e_sat;
    fclose(f);
    buf[read] = '\0';

    for (char* next_VMA = buf; *next_VMA != '\0'; )
        next_VMA = parse_VMA_(next_VMA, stats);

    stats->anon_kb = stats->vm_kb - stats->misc_kb;
    stats->unallocated_kb = stats->anon_kb - stats->rss_kb - stats->swap_kb;

    free(buf);
    return 0;

e_open: ko_("opening smaps"); free(buf); return -1;
e_unbuf: ko_("unbuffering smaps"); fclose(f); free(buf); return -1;
e_read: ko_("reading smaps"); fclose(f); free(buf); return -1;
e_sat: ko_("reading smaps (buffer saturation)"); fclose(f); free(buf); return -1;
}

static char* parse_VMA_(char* VMA, struct mem_stats_* stats)
{
    char* perms = jump_token_(VMA);
    char* inode = jump_token_(jump_token_(jump_token_(perms + 3)));
    int is_anon_prv = *inode == '0' && inode[1] <= ' ' && perms[3] == 'p';

    VMA = find_next_line_(inode); /* Skip header. */

    int l_sz_kb = 0;
    VMA = find_field_(VMA, "Size:", 5, &l_sz_kb);

    stats->vm_kb += l_sz_kb;

    if (is_anon_prv) {
        VMA = find_field_(VMA, "Rss:", 4, &stats->rss_kb);
        VMA = find_field_(VMA, "Swap:", 5, &stats->swap_kb);
    } else
        stats->misc_kb += l_sz_kb;

    return find_next_VMA_(VMA);
}

/* `str` must point to a character of the previous token, and this function 
    search the start of the next token. */
static char* jump_token_(char* str)
{
    while (*++str > ' ')
        ;

    while (*++str <= ' ')
        ;

    return str;
}

/* Jump from line to line until finding a line starting by `field`, store the 
   value of the line in `out`, and jumps to the start of the next line. */
static char* find_field_(char* str, char const* field, int field_sz, int* out)
{
    while (memcmp(str, field, field_sz) != 0)
        str = find_next_line_(str);

    *out += strtoul(jump_token_(str + field_sz - 1), &str, 10);
    return find_next_line_(str);
}

/* `str` must point to the start of a line */
static char* find_next_VMA_(char* str)
{
    while (*str != '\0' && *str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z')
        str = find_next_line_(str);

    return str;
}

/* str must not point to '\n' */
static char* find_next_line_(char* str)
{
    while (*++str != '\n')
        ;

    return ++str;
}

int main()
{
    print_perf_stats();
    return 0;
}
```

What is confusing for me is that running this program multiple times, the result time is always around 1ms, but sometimes that ms appears as being expent on kernel mode, and sometimes appears as being user mode. Output of multiple executions:

```
$ ./a.out
[Obs: MEMSTATS (kB)][Vm: 4828 [PrvAnon: 2416 [Rss: 60][Swap: 0][Unalloc: 2356]] [Misc: 2412]]
[Obs: CPUSTATS][times u/s: 0s1683us/0s0us][faults min/maj: 91/0][cswitches (vol/unvol): 0/0]
$ ./a.out
[Obs: MEMSTATS (kB)][Vm: 4828 [PrvAnon: 2416 [Rss: 56][Swap: 0][Unalloc: 2360]] [Misc: 2412]]
[Obs: CPUSTATS][times u/s: 0s1665us/0s0us][faults min/maj: 87/0][cswitches (vol/unvol): 0/0]
$ ./a.out
[Obs: MEMSTATS (kB)][Vm: 4828 [PrvAnon: 2416 [Rss: 56][Swap: 0][Unalloc: 2360]] [Misc: 2412]]
[Obs: CPUSTATS][times u/s: 0s0us/0s981us][faults min/maj: 90/0][cswitches (vol/unvol): 0/1]
$ ./a.out
[Obs: MEMSTATS (kB)][Vm: 4828 [PrvAnon: 2416 [Rss: 60][Swap: 0][Unalloc: 2356]] [Misc: 2412]]
[Obs: CPUSTATS][times u/s: 0s0us/0s1479us][faults min/maj: 88/0][cswitches (vol/unvol): 0/0]
```

I wonder what is going on (when the measurement is counted as user time, then kernel time is 0, and viceversa). Which internal timers is the kernel using to count these times? How much can you trust `getrusage`?

The compilation flags are: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Werror -O3`

The linux kernel version is: `5.15.0-78-generic` (under Ubuntu 22.04)

CPU: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz`

**NOTE:** I think the reason is that,

- Kernel jiffies happens at 250 Hz (`grep /boot/config-$(uname -r) CONFIG_HZ`), and the runtime of my code is lower than a jiffie.
- The kernel is not using the TSC counter to measure every-time the process enters and exits kernel mode (`grep /boot/config-$(uname) CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING=n`). Instead, at each jiffie, it looks if the process is in user or kernel mode, and adds the corresponding time-interval (1/250Hz = 4ms) to the utime or stime counter. On the other hand, the scheduler is using the TSC counter (or any other clock to get a high-precision accounting) to measure the total, real-time consumed by the process and adjust the utime and stime accordingly.

In total:

- If the jiffy happened while the process was in a syscall: stime += 4ms
- Otherwise: utime += 4ms
- Since my process takes less than one jiffy, one of utime or stime is 0, and the other have a value of 4ms.
- Finally, it looks at the total, accurate real time calculated by the scheduler, and assigns that total to the non-zero variable.
- That last step explains why the utime or stime is never a multiple of 4ms.

Comment: Old question, but for lack of other answer, your code experiences the same thing the Linux `time` shell commands does -- and for the same reason it outputs duration in a combination of `real`, `user` and `sys` times. On Linux, or any modern OS where programs compete for time, how long your program takes to run on real wall-clock time depends on what else is running at the same time. Further causing a shuffling of the response on how much user-time and kernel-time (sys) is needed depends on what is available in cache at the time of measure. The `time` source would be worth a look.